# Add html input value to the d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to pass html input values to the d3js script to make it a little more dynamic visualization. Below is the script :

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width");

  var format = d3.format(",d");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var pack = d3.pack()
      .size([width, width])
      .padding(1.5);

  //     function add() {
  //        rat = document.getElementsByName("ratings").value;
  //        chk = document.getElementsByName("checkins").value;
  //
  //   var sum = parseInt(rat) + parseInt(chk);
  //   alert(sum);
  // }

  console.log(d3.select("body"));

  d3.csv("austin_fsq.csv", function(d,ra,ch) {
    d.sno = +d.sno;
     if (d.sno && d.rating  >= 9 && d.value <= 500) return d;
// if (d.sno && d.rating  >= "+ra+" && d.value <= "+ch+") return d;
  }, function(error, classes) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var root = d3.hierarchy({children: classes})
        .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .each(function(d) {
          if (id = d.data.id) {
            var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
            d.id = id;
            d.package = id.slice(0, i);
            d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
          }
        });

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack(root).leaves())
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.package); });

    node.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return "clip-" + d.id; })
      .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; });

    node.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.id + ")"; })
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data(function(d) { return d.class.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g); })
      .enter().append("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d, i, nodes) { return 13 + (i - nodes.length / 2 - 0.5) * 10; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

    node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.id + "\n" + format(d.value); });
  });
```

So if you see here :

```
     if (d.sno && d.rating  >= 9 && d.value <= 500) return d;
```

I have coded the values which I want to pick from html input element. I did try which I commented out below. What could I do to get this input element values for rating and value.Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing one of the most important parts: the HTML of the input. So, I'll suppose you're using a simple number input, like this:

```
<input type="number">
```

To get the value of the number entered in this input with D3, select the input by tag, ID or class, and use `this.value` to get its value:

```js
d3.select("#myInput").on("change", function(){
    console.log("The value is: " + this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="number">
```

However, you have a additional problem here:

If you simply set the value to a variable, like this:

```
var myInput;
d3.select("#myInput").on("change", function(){
    myInput = this.value
})
```

You **cannot** use that variable inside your `d3.csv` row (also called accessor) function, because when the browser reaches `d3.csv`, the row function it will run regardless you have an input value or not, and the variable will be `undefined` in the second case.

That being said, the solution is calling your `d3.csv` function **after** the input has been entered. Wrap it in another function and call that function after you get an input:

```
var myInput:
d3.select("#myInput").on("change", function(){
    myInput = this.value;
    //call your chart function here
})
```

Then, you can use the input value:

```
if (d.sno && d.rating  >= myInput && d.value <= 500) return d;
```

Comment: I just did that and it still doesnt pick up the value from the html input: https://jsfiddle.net/r80cu9wa/1/

Comment: It's hard to debug without a working code, but here you have "ratings" instead of "myInput": `if (d.sno && d.rating  >= ratings && d.value <= 500) return d;`

Comment: Besides that, it is `var myInput =`, not `var myInput:`, which is a syntax error in JavaScript (this is one error which I saw, there can be others...). So, please provide a working code, then I can help you.

Comment: You still don't have a working code. Create a code that works **without** the input and I'll show you how to add the input.

Comment: I just put the code here :https://bl.ocks.org/senthilthyagarajan/2e879cdc95f6d3d447e8a95d6d676717

I want to get input for ratings and value from the html elements and also wanted to know if the same could be done for changing the csv so if I have a few different cities the use can select a city in the dropdown and the csv would change.Thanks for you help :)

Comment: As I said before, please create a working, live code. What am I gonna do with a Github code?

Comment: Sorry for the last update. I am trying to get the live code using fiddle .I am unable to use the cvs in fiddle and trying to figure that out.Hence i put my bl.ock or git code.

Comment: Finally got the live code on plunker :https://plnkr.co/edit/ij5yPqM8IgGzVRFdCroB?p=preview

Comment: Ok, here is the updated code: https://plnkr.co/edit/WgGs5bcHUP3AmjncivPM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot I did get that working . But if I test it with input value as 5000 the output I get shows that it doesnt filter for records less than 5000. If you could hover on a big circle it shows the same value and it shows up greater than 5000 ones too.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Since that's another issue (regarding the value itself) and it's not related to your specific problem here, which was solved, I suggest you post *another* question with this new issue.